# Why are sapply() and options() "undesirable"?

Tags: r, sapply, lintr

Jim Hester's "lintr" package contains many different linters for R. The [README for the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lintr/readme/README.html#available-linters:%7E:text=undesirable_function_linter%3A%20report%20the%20use%20of%20undesirable,or%20sapply%20and%20suggest%20an%20alternative.) describes one of the linters in this way:

> `undesirable_function_linter:` report the use of undesirable functions, e.g. options or sapply and suggest an alternative.

I was surprised. I've been using R for many years, and I've been using `options()` and `sapply()` for many years. What makes them undesirable? And are there better alternatives?

I know about `getOption()`, but it's not a substitute for `options()`. I also know about the `*apply()` variants, `Map()`, and the Tidyverse `map` functions. The Tidyverse functions do seem better to me on the whole than `sapply()` or `Map()` -- I prefer the defaults and the ordering of arguments in the Tidyverse functions -- but I wouldn't have thought to call `sapply()` "undesirable."

Comment: `sapply` "... tries to simplify the result, so it can return a list, a vector, or a matrix. This makes it difficult to program with, and it should be avoided in non-interactive settings." See https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html?q=sapply#map-atomic.

Comment: Use `vapply` instead of `sapply`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the header for that function,

```
function(fun = default_undesirable_functions)
```

you see that it records its choices in `default_undesirable_functions`, and if you look at that object, you'll see:

```
...
$options
[1] "use withr::with_options()"
...
$sapply
[1] "use vapply() or lapply()"
...
```

From the alternatives, you can guess at why the author thinks those functions are "undesirable":

- `options()` is bad because it has global side effects.  The `withr::with_options()` alternative keeps any changes to the options local.
- `sapply()` is bad because `vapply()` is safer (as documented in `?sapply`).